# Configuring sendmail to only use starttls in client mode

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, sendmail, tls

Is it possible to configure sendmail so that it will only connect to a remote smtp server when STARTTLS is offered there? I so - how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems very similar to the question at [iptables only allow smtp connections with start tls](https://serverfault.com/questions/188029/iptables-only-allow-smtp-connections-with-start-tls) where several suggestions are made, including mine.